# What is the evidence of interpreting $g_{\mu\nu}$ as the metric of space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, reference-frames, metric-tensor

I think if we don't mention the meaning of $g_{\mu\nu}$ as the metric of space-time, we can still construct the equation of motion and Einstein field equation in a way such that $g_{\mu\nu}$ is just a tensor field in a "flat" (independent) space-time.

What is the reason that $g_{\mu\nu}$ must be the geometric of space-time (according to experiments or self-consistency of the theory,...) besides the fact that it is an elegant interpretation?

Comment: I personally think that it is because it is used in the generalisation of the pythagoras theorem(the expansion for dS^2) which essentially guarantees that the spacetime is flat or not(flat if it holds, curved if it doesn't)....IN CARTESIAN COORDINATES

Comment: So the space-time is flat or not is just wave we describe $g$?

Comment: $g_{\mu\nu}$ is *defined* as the metric describing the geometry of spacetime. It can describe any hypothetical spacetime. I'm not sure what @GRrocks is referring to, perhaps he is unaware that $g_{\mu\nu}$ isn't necessarily the Minkowski metric. But using it as the metric is not an interpretation. It's a definition

Comment: @Jim I think there may be a different version of GR where the definition of $g$ is just a tensor field and provide all the results of GR. That's why I ask, why should $g$ be defined as the metric

Comment: Well, I'm a cosmologist and I've never come across a situation where $g$ is a tensor field and *not* a metric. If you can refer me to any of those, I'll be glad to look at them and opine

Comment: There is some reason why $g$ is always a metric, that is what I'm asking. I just think that with the Einstein field equation and the geodesic equation one can derived the dynamics of mass and gravity without saying $g$ is a metric or just simply a tensor field.

Comment: I think the question comes from a misunderstanding of what a metric is. In this context a metric is any symmetric rank to tensor. So $g$ of course is a metric.

Comment: Indeed, whatever you substitute in for $g$, that will be the metric you use because $g$ is defined as the metric

Comment: so Gravity is the Geometry because we define geometry to be gravity?

Comment: No, geometry in this context means specifying a metric, and $g$ is exactly that.

Comment: @Jim, Let me elaborate-You can write dS^2 = dx^2 + dy^2. For m dimensions, it is $ds^2 = \Sigma_m dx^m dx^m$, or more generally, $\delta_{mn}dx^m dx^n$. You then replace the kronecker delta by $g$....If m=n=2, this is good old pythagoras, otherwise there is something wrong with our coordinate choice or the geometry itself....so yeah, it does describe the geometry, and no, I didn't assume $g$ to be minkowsky metric..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one. In fact, I know for sure that approaches has been proposed which treat $g_{\mu \nu}$ as a physical field, which can be interpreted as the metric in some effective Riemannian manifold.

Take a look at [the relativistic theory of gravitation](http://mirtitles.org/2012/07/07/the-relativistic-theory-of-gravitation-logunov-mestvirishvili/) by Logunov. It attempts to solve the problem of energy conservation by imposing that $g_{\mu \nu}$ is not geometrical, but rather physical.

But this approach is not widely accepted, and there is a good reason for that: elegance of General Relativity and its great predictive power.

Comment: "...In analysing the evolution of the universe, RTG concludes that the universe is infinite and “flat” and predicts a large “latent” mass in it. This “latent” mass exceeds the observable mass of the universe by a factor of 40."

Comment: @DirkBruere Yes. So? I never said RTG was correct. My point is: it is theoretically possible to treat $g_{\mu \nu}$ as a physical field.

Comment: My comment was to indicate that it seems a rather prescient indicator of Dark Matter

Comment: @DirkBruere, wow, I see. Thank you for this information. Still, it is not widely accepted for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

if gμν is a tensor field, then as per experimental verification it has to interact in the same way as photon as well as massive objects.interaction does not depend on other objects only on source objects that are causing stress energy tensor.

another evidence is gravitational waves if detected. then we can see the difference more easily. because at the LIGO facility , two beams of lights are bouncing in perpendicular direction , if gravitational waves strong enough sensed by ligo detector that can change the distance between arms of detector.so gravitational waves is changing the spacetime between them physically. see the effects of gravitational waves.

so we can say it is the metric of manifold not a field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point to understand is that metrics  exist which describe a flat space-time and others which describe a curved space. Both can be distinguished by the Riemann's curvature tensor which is zero for a metric which belongs to a flat space-time whereas for a curved space it is non-zero.
Therefore if the curvature tensor is evaluated to be non-zero, also the "surrounding" space-time must be curved. I cannot imagine it otherwise.

Example: do a coordinate tramsformation $x=x' cos(\Omega t) - y' sin(\Omega t)$; $y=x' cos(\Omega t) + y' sin(\Omega t)$ $z'=z$ on $ds^2 =dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$ One gets a non-diagonal metric which belongs to a flat space-time. Compute the Riemann tensor to check it out (I admit : a lot of work). But I think the idea is suggestive enough to be clear.

2.) the Schwarzschild metric. This metric cannot be changed to a flat metric. It is really associated to a curved space. There is no coordinate transformation which could make the space-time described by a Schwarzschild metric everywhere flat (at most it could be "flat-like" at one single point ... in fact for real flatness several points are needed with flat-like behaviour).

Again, I cannot imagine to disconnect $g_{\mu\nu}$ from its original function  $ds^2 =g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$. I could attribute to $g_{\mu\nu}$ everything what I would want except $ds^2 =g_{\mu\nu}dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu}$.
However, matrix elements of $g_{\mu\nu}$ were already measured for instance by measuring the time dilation of clocks at different places in 
a gravitational field or by the light deviation in the metric of the sun. So the metric is real as an electromagnetical field is.